# Help show $\lim \limits_{R\to \infty} \frac{1}{{2R}}\int_{-R}^R {\left[ \sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{{\cos\sqrt n x}}{{1+{n^2}}} \right]dx} =1$

Tags: real-analysis

The question is

> Prove that the series $f\left( x \right) = \mathop \sum \limits_{n = 0}^\infty  \frac{{\cos \sqrt n x}}{{1 + {n^2}}}$ converges uniformly in $\Bbb{R}$ and show that $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{R \to \infty } \frac{1}{{2R}}\mathop \smallint \limits_{ - R}^R f\left( x \right)dx = 1$.

I know how to do the first half of the problem. Let ${f_n}(x) = \frac{{\cos \sqrt n x}}{{1 + {n^2}}}$, since $\mathop \sum \limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\left\| {{f_n}} \right\|_\infty } < \mathop \sum \limits_{n = 0}^\infty  \frac{1}{{1 + {n^2}}} <  + \infty $, then $f(x) = \mathop \sum \limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {f_n}(x)$ converges uniformly.

But I have difficulty with the second half.

I have tried exchanging the integration and series ($\int_{ - R}^R {\mathop \sum \limits_{n = 0}^\infty  \frac{{\cos \sqrt n x}}{{1 + {n^2}}}dx}  = \mathop \sum \limits_{n = 0}^\infty  \int_{ - R}^R {\frac{{\cos \sqrt n x}}{{1 + {n^2}}}dx} $ since $\frac{{\cos \sqrt n x}}{{1 + {n^2}}} \ge  - \frac{1}{{1 + {n^2}}}$ where the later is integrable on $[-R,R]$) but then get stuck. The form of the problem also looks like mean-value theorem, but I am not sure if MVT is applicable.

Thank you.

Comment: I guess that you should conclude the continuity of $f$ from the first part. And then https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_integration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:In regards to the second part, you have (by absolute convergence)
$$ \frac{1}{2R} \int_{-R}^R f(x) dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2R} \int_{-R}^R  \frac{ \cos ( \sqrt{ n } x ) }{1 + n^2 } dx = 1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2R} \frac{ 2\sin(\sqrt{n} R)  }{\sqrt{n}(1+n^2)} $$
Now take the limit.

Comment: That's how to show it!  Well done.  +1